# sed or awk: delete n lines following a pattern

Tags: unix, sed, awk

How would I mix patterns and numeric ranges in sed (or any similar tool - awk for example)? What I want to do is match certain lines in a file, and delete the next n lines before proceeding, and I want to do that as part of a pipeline.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

I'll have a go at this.

To delete 5 lines after a pattern (including the line with the pattern):

```
sed -e '/pattern/,+5d' file.txt
```

To delete 5 lines after a pattern (excluding the line with the pattern):

```
sed -e '/pattern/{n;N;N;N;N;d}' file.txt
```

Comment: Note that the `+N` pattern is a GNU extension. Change the first `n` to an `N` in your second example to make it include the line with the pattern.

Comment: how to delete all lines after the pattern is matched ? I am using sed -e '/<!--#content end--></div>/,$d' out.txt
but it gives error saying : 
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: extra characters after command
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's happening is similar but slightly different in each case.

In the first recipe, `/pattern/,+5` defines a range, which starts with a line containing "pattern" (`/pattern/`) and ends 5 lines later (`+5`).  The last character `d` is a command to run on each line in that range, which is "delete".

In the second recipe, instead of matching a range, it matches just at the line containing the pattern (`/pattern/`) and then runs a series of commands: `{n;N;N;N;N;d}`, which basically prints the next line (`n`) and then reads and finally discards the next 4 lines (`N;N;N;N;d`).

Comment: On Mac/OS X systems you need to add a semicolon before the closing bracket: `sed -e '/pattern/{n;N;N;N;N;d;}' file.txt`

Comment: In the 2nd flavour how to specific a number for the next N lines. I have to delete next 52 lines, so writing 52 time `N;` is tedious.

Comment: Just wondering, is there any way/option to perform this task interactively ?

Comment: @pimlottc @dogbane If I want use the `sed -e '/pattern/{n;N;N;N;N;d}' file.txt` model in reverse, that is, delete 5 lines BEFORE a pattern (excluding the line with the pattern)? Could you update the answer to include this extra case? Thanks! =D

Comment: For completeness: To **delete all lines following a certain pattern** `something` do: `sed -E '/^something$/,$d'`, where `-E` is the POSIX portability extended regex.

Comment: how would one add to this `On second match?`

Answer (score 19):

Without GNU extensions (e.g. on macOS):

To delete 5 lines after a pattern (including the line with the pattern)

```
 sed -e '/pattern/{N;N;N;N;d;}' file.txt
```

Add `-i ''` to edit in-place.

Comment: Any ideas on how to delete several lines before and after the match altogether? Can't find any suitable POSIX variant.

Answer (score 7):

**Simple `awk` solutions:**

Assume that the regular expression to use for finding matching lines is stored in shell variable `$regex`, and the count of lines to skip in `$count`.

If the **matching line should *also* be skipped** (`$count + 1` lines are skipped):

```
... | awk -v regex="$regex" -v count="$count" \
  '$0 ~ regex { skip=count; next } --skip >= 0 { next } 1'
```

If the **matching line should *not* be skipped** (`$count` lines *after* the match are skipped):

```
... | awk -v regex="$regex" -v count="$count" \
  '$0 ~ regex { skip=count; print; next } --skip >= 0 { next } 1'
```

**Explanation:**

- `-v regex="$regex" -v count="$count"` defines `awk` variables based on *shell* variables of the same name.
- `$0 ~ regex` matches the line of interest

  - `{ skip=count; next }` initializes the skip count and proceeds to the next line, effectively skipping the matching line; in the 2nd solution, the `print` before `next` ensures that it is *not* skipped.
  - `--skip >= 0` decrements the skip count and takes action if it is (still) >= 0, implying that the line at hand should be skipped.
  - `{ next }` proceeds to the next line, effectively skipping the current line
- `1` is a commonly used shorthand for `{ print }`; that is, the current line is simply printed

  - Only non-matching and non-skipped lines reach this command.
  - <sup>The reason that `1` is equivalent to `{ print }` is that `1` is interpreted as a Boolean pattern that by definition always evaluates to true, which means that its associated action (block) is unconditionally executed. Since there is *no* associated action in this case, `awk` defaults to *printing* the line.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<! >pattern_number.txt
> 5 3
> 10 1
> 15 5
> !
sed 's|\(\S*\) \(\S*\)|/\1/,+\2{//!d}|' pattern_number.txt |
sed -f - <(seq 21)
1 
2
3
4
5
9
10
12
13
14
15
21
```

Comment: A clever (albeit GNU-Sed-specific) solution, but few people will benefit from it, unless you add an explanation.
 `pattern_number.txt` is a 2-column file containing the pattern to match in the 1st column, and in the 2nd the number of lines to skip.
The first `sed` command transforms the file into a `sed` script that performs the corresponding matching and skipping; that script is provided via
`-f` and stdin (`-`) to the 2nd `sed` command. The 2nd `sed` command operates on a sample ad-hoc input file formed from the output of `seq 21` to demonstrate that it works.

Comment: Also, the solution comes with one caveat: the method it uses _not_ to skip the first line (the one matching the pattern) has the side effect of also not skipping _duplicate_ lines in the range.

Comment: That is an impressive use of sed.

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl

```
$ cat delete_5lines.txt
1
2
3
4
5 hello
6
7
8
9
10
11 hai
$ perl -ne ' BEGIN{$y=1} $y=$.  if /hello/ ; print if $y==1 or $.-$y > 5 ' delete_5lines.txt
1
2
3
4
11 hai
$
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution allows you to pass "n" as a parameter and it will read your patterns from a file:

```
awk -v n=5 '
    NR == FNR {pattern[$0]; next}
    {
        for (patt in pattern) {
            if ($0 ~ patt) {
                print # remove if you want to exclude a matched line
                for (i=0; i<n; i++) getline
                next
            }
        }
        print
    }
' file.with.patterns -
```

The file named "-" means stdin for awk, so this is suitable for your pipeline

Comment: awk is capable of being a lot more perl-like than i realised!

Answer (score 1):

Patterns may show up within the next 5 lines, so a straight-up delete would inadvertently skip past criteria matches that would extend the boundary of "next 5 lines". Using **`awk`**, just set `__` to # of lines skipped, and `FS` to the matching criteria's pattern (i.e. properly-escaped `ERE` `regex`).

By utilizing `FS`, checking whether pattern has matched or not is straight up `NF > 1`. Otherwise, every line would be matched twice - first by `FS` to split the input row into unnecessary fields, then once more by the desired pattern itself.

```
jot 30 |
```

---

```
mawk '(_ < NR) * (NF < 2 || _ = NR + __)' FS='(.1|9)$' __=5
```

---

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9  <—  9 bypassed 10-14, and 11 bypassed 12-16
17
18
19 <— 19 bypassed 20-24, and 21 bypassed 22-26
27 
28
29 <— 29 bypassed 30
```

( *Before* **`_`** *gets explicitly assigned, depending on context, it's either empty string* **`""`** *or numeric* **`0`** *, so short of fudging* **`NR`** *itself, all lines prior to the 1st pattern match would get auto printed, including blank lines.* )