# How can I use "sed" to delete 2 lines after match/matches?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have the following command : `sed -i -e '/match1/,+2d' filex`, which deletes 2 lines after finding the match "match1" in the file "file x". I want to add several matches to it, like match1, match 2 ....

So it will delete 2 lines after finding any of the matches, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: can you given an input/output example to make it clearer what you expect?

Comment: Is there anything wrong in your case with the obvious `/match1/,+2d;/match2/,+2d`? It won't recognize overlaps, but your original expression doesn't, either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed or awk: delete n lines following a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-or-awk-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46173433/2506817

Answer (score 37):

Two ways, depending upon the sed version and platform:

```
sed -e '/match1/,+2d' -e '/match2/,+2d' < oldfile > newfile
```

or

```
sed -e '/match1\|match2/,+2d' < oldfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 14):

Not a sed user but it seems to me you could use :

```
sed -i -e '/(match1|match2)/,+2d' filex
```

Otherwise you could, if that's possible for you to do, do :

```
sed -i -e '/match1/,+2d' filex && sed -i -e '/match2/,+2d' filex
```

EDIT: Looks like I had the right idea but ziu got it.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand you correctly, you want

```
sed -e '/match1/,+2d' input.txt
```

For example, create input with `seq 10 | sed '3i match1' > input.txt`:

```
1
2
match1
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The output of `sed -e '/match1/,+2d' input.txt` would be:

```
1
2
5
6
7
8
9
10
```