# How to exclude several lines around match with grep or similar tool?

Tags: awk, grep, ack

I can find all non-matched lines of file with `grep -v 'my_pattern' some_file`. Also i can print few strings before/after/around match with `-A`, `-B` or `-C` options of grep. But i can't combine these two options to exclude lines with pattern and certain amount of lines near matched lines - grep shows entire file as result. For example, i have log with a lot of patterns like this:

```
25.02.2012 10:41:37 here goes memory state
25MiB free
16MiB allocated
max free block is 4MiB
```

I'd like to filter them. Of course, i can write custom perl/awk script, but is there more elegant way to do this?

Comment: The awk solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9443740/851677.

Comment: Use sed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **`vim`** text editor:

```
:g/my_pattern/-2,//+2d
```

Comment: one thing i can't undestand - what's the difference between `:g/my_pattern/-2,//+2d` and `:g/my_pattern/-2,+2d`? It looks like they both do the same thing.

Comment: I don't know what the difference is, but I tried both out on a large file. ``:g/my_pattern/-2,+2d`` worked as expected, but ``:g/my_pattern/-2,//+2d`` removed more lines than expected.

Answer (score 1):

A grep solution:

`grep -C2 pattern file | grep -vFf- file`

This uses `grep -C2` to get the lines from `file` that you wish to exclude.

Then `grep -vFf-` takes those lines from stdin and will report all lines not matching.

Caution: This will eliminate all lines matching the 'context' elsewhere in `file`.  So if the context contains a blank line, you will remove all blank lines.