# Delete n1 previous lines and n2 lines following with respect to a line containing a pattern

Tags: bash, unix, sed

```
sed -e '/XXXX/,+4d' fv.out
```

I have to find a particular pattern in a file and delete 5 lines above and 4 lines below it simultaneously. I found out that the line above removes the line containing the pattern and four lines below it.

```
sed -e '/XXXX/,~5d' fv.out
```

In sed manual it was given that ~ represents the lines which is followed by the pattern. But when i tried it, it was the lines following the pattern that was deleted.

So, how do I delete 5 lines above and 4 lines below a line containing the pattern simultaneously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way using `sed`, assuming that the patterns are not close enough each other:

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## If line doesn't match the pattern...
/pattern/ ! { 

    ## Append line to 'hold space'.
    H   

    ## Copy content of 'hold space' to 'pattern space' to work with it.
    g   

    ## If there are more than 5 lines saved, print and remove the first
    ## one. It's like a FIFO.
    /\(\n[^\n]*\)\{6\}/ {

        ## Delete the first '\n' automatically added by previous 'H' command.
        s/^\n//
        ## Print until first '\n'.
        P   
        ## Delete data printed just before.
        s/[^\n]*//
        ## Save updated content to 'hold space'.
        h   
    } 

### Added to fix an error pointed out by potong in comments.
### =======================================================
    ## If last line, print lines left in 'hold space'.
    $ { 
        x   
        s/^\n//
        p   
    } 
### =======================================================


    ## Read next line.
    b   
}

## If line matches the pattern...
/pattern/ {

    ## Remove all content of 'hold space'. It has the five previous
    ## lines, which won't be printed.
    x   
    s/^.*$//
    x   

    ## Read next four lines and append them to 'pattern space'.
    N ; N ; N ; N 

    ## Delete all.
    s/^.*$//
}
```

Run like:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for (I have the occurrences of pattern separated by at least 20 lines).

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `awk`:

```
awk '$0 ~ "XXXX" { lines2del = 5; nlines = 0; }
     nlines == 5 { print lines[NR%5]; nlines-- }
     lines2del == 0 { lines[NR%5] = $0; nlines++ }
     lines2del > 0 { lines2del-- }
     END { while (nlines-- > 0)  { print lines[(NR - nlines) % 5] } }' fv.out
```

**Update:**

This is the script explained:

- I remember the last 5 lines in the array `lines` using rotatory indexes (NR%5; NR is the record number; in this case lines).
- If I find the pattern in the current line (`$0 ~ "XXXX`; `$0` being the current record: in this case a line; and `~` being the *Extended Regular Expression* match operator), I reset the number of lines read and note that I have 5 lines to delete (including the current line).
- If I already read 5 lines, I print the current line.
- If I do not have lines to delete (which is also true if I had read 5 lines, I put the current line in the buffer and increment the number of lines.  Note how the number of lines is decremented and then incremented if a line is printed.
- If lines need to be deleted, I do not print anything and decrement the number of lines to delete.
- At the end of the script, I print all the lines that are in the array.

My original version of the script was the following, but I ended up optimizing it to the above version:

```
awk '$0 ~ "XXXX" { lines2del = 5; nlines = 0; }
     lines2del == 0 && nlines == 5 { print lines[NR%5]; lines[NR%5] }
     lines2del == 0 && nlines < 5 { lines[NR%5] = $0; nlines++ }
     lines2del > 0 { lines2del-- }
     END { while (nlines-- > 0)  { print lines[(NR - nlines) % 5] } }' fv.out
```

`awk` is a great tool !  I strongly recommend that you find a tutorial on the net and read it.  One important thing: `awk` works with **Extended Regular Expressions** (*ERE*).  Their syntax is a little different from **Standard Regular Expression** (*RE*) used in `sed`, but all that can be done with RE can be done with ERE.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. But, I am an absolute beginner to awk. So, can you please explain the script? Also, how do you fix n1 and n2 separately? It seems to me that here you have taken n1=n2.

Comment: I do not understand your n1/n2 question.  Explaining the script is very forward, I am updating the post.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering that how do you delete 4 lines below (n2) the pattern. Since I have no experience in awk, I was thinking that you put the number of lines after (n2) and before (n1) the pattern as the same. I was very much confused. I think it would be great if I learned awk too.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to read 5 lines without printing them.  If you find the pattern, delete the unprinted lines and the 4 lines bellow.  If you do not find the pattern, remember the current line and print the 1st unprinted line.  At the end, print what is unprinted.

```
sed -n -e '/XXXX/,+4{x;s/.*//;x;d}' -e '1,5H' -e '6,${H;g;s/\n//;P;s/[^\n]*//;h}' -e '${g;s/\n//;p;d}' fv.out
```

Of course, this only works if you have one occurrence of your pattern in the file.  If you have many, you need to read 5 new lines after finding your pattern, and it gets complicated if you again have your pattern in those lines.  In this case, I think sed is not the right tool.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for the first occurrence. But, I have a lot of occurrences of the pattern. May be I'll have to put it in a loop so that grep shows no more occurrence of the pattern. What do you suggest other than using sed?

Comment: I was working on the awk solution bellow.  In my opinion, it is much better because easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'H;$!d;g;s/\([^\n]*\n\)\{5\}[^\n]*PATTERN\([^\n]*\n\)\{5\}//g;s/.//' file
```

or this:

```
awk --posix -vORS='' -vRS='([^\n]*\n){5}[^\n]*PATTERN([^\n]*\n){5}' 1 file
```

a more efficient sed solution:

```
sed ':a;/PATTERN/,+4d;/\([^\n]*\n\)\{5\}/{P;D};$q;N;ba' file
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. But, I have some huge files and it takes up a lot of time.

Comment: @PopulationXplosive I've added an awk solution. It may be faster.

Comment: Thanks. The awk solution also takes up a lot of time. But the new sed solution is quite fast. Nice one-liner indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to output the result to a file instead of stdout, `vim` can do it quite efficiently:

```
vim -c 'g/pattern/-5,+4d' -c 'w! outfile|q!' infile
```

or

```
vim -c 'g/pattern/-5,+4d' -c 'x' infile
```

to edit the file in-place.