# Find entry in .netrc file via bash and delete it if exists

Tags: linux, macos, bash, replace, find

In bash, how do I search for the following string in a file `~/.netrc` and delete that line **plus the next two lines** if found:

```
machine api.mydomain.com
```

Example is:

```
machine api.mydomain.com
   user foo
   password bar
```

It should delete all three lines, but I can't match `user` and `password` since those are unknown. The only fixed value is `machine api.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -i '' '/^machine api.mydomain.com$/{N;N;d;}' ~/.netrc
```

When this finds the line `machine api.mydomain.com`, it reads in two more lines and then deletes them all.  Other lines pass through unchanged.

For GNU sed, the argument to `-i` is optional.  For OSX (BSD) sed, the argument is required but is allowed to be empty as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Let's google it together - [sed or awk: delete n lines following a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern)

So, the answer is `sed -e '/machine api.mydomain.com/,+2d' ~/.netrc`. Add `-i` flag if changes need to be done in place.

Comment: Does this work on OS X? Getting `sed: 1: "/machine api.mydomain.c ...": expected context address` I need this to work on standard Linux and OS X.

Comment: @Justin For OSX, add `-i` then space then `''`.  In other words, use `sed -i '' -e '/machine api.mydomain.com/,+2d' ~/.netrc`

Comment: Still not working. `sed -i '' -e '/machine api.mydomain.com/,+2d' ~/.netrc`
sed: 1: "/machine api.mydomain.c ...": expected context address

Comment: @Justin __"expected context address"__: That is a different problem.  The fancy range (`+2`) is not supported by OSX/BSD.  I just wrote an answer that avoids that.