# remove n lines after matching pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript I am trying to remove 3 lines after matching pattern (including line with matching pattern)

```
#Guest 
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I know how to do it sed , look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-or-awk-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern). Don't how to translate to javascript

```
??? data.replace(/.*#Guest.*+5d/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```
^([\s\S]*?)\n#Guest.*(?:\n.*){3}
```

And replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rO0yD8/10

```
var re = /^([\s\S]*?)\n#Guest.*(?:\n.*){3}/g; 
var str = 'sdfdsf\nsdfsdf\nsdf\nsdf\n#Guest\nline 1\nline 2\nline 3\ndsfsdf\nsd\nf\nsd\nf\n';
var subst = '$1'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Appreciate , when I paste this '''' set wlan vap SSID enable
set wlan enable
#Guest Wireless (Password must be 8-64 characters)
add wlan vap ssid 
set wlan vap  security-type WPA/WPA2''' I got zero matches ?

Comment: @irom no you just need to press `update regex` and share d link

Comment: I see, when I change from  PCRE to JS it doesn't work ? Very close, let me try again