# sed n doesn't seem to work quite the way I thought it would

Tags: sed

I was trying to copy an example I found here : http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35a

here is the sed pattern

```
/^begin$/,/^end$/{
    /begin/n
    /end/!d
}
```

here's the first file

```
begin
one
end
last line
```

and here's the second

```
begin
end
last line
```

when I run the sed on the first file it deletes what's between the begin/end and all is well. When I run it on the second, it appears to miss the "end" and deletes the rest of the file.

running on first file

```
$ sed -f x.sed a
begin
end
last line
```

running on second

```
$ sed -f x.sed b
begin
end
```

notice how "last line" is missing on the second run.

I thought that "n" would print the current pattern and suck in the next one. It would then hit the /end/ command and process that.

as it is, it seems like it's somehow causing the end of the range to be missed. Will somebody explain what is happening?

Comment: May not be helpful: if you can use awk, it gets more reliable: `awk -v p=1 '/^end$/ {p=1}; p; /^begin$/ {p=0}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
/^begin$/,/^end$/{
    /^begin$\|^end$/!d
}
```

---

Why was your command wrong?

The `n` command was wrong there. In the second example it will:

1. `begin` ---> n read next line(**important:** this does not affect the state of the range address (begin,end))

   1a. `end` ---> `/end/!` does not apply. Don't delete the line
2. `last line`  ---> `/end/!` applies. Delete the line. (`sed` is still searching for a line that contains `end` because the `n` command skipped that line)

Comment: can you explain what it did there? I can see that it doesn't work, but it feels like it should.

Comment: Added explanation. I hope it helps.

Comment: so it reads two lines as it goes through the loop, and skips over the range check?

Answer (score 0):

found another way around after @hek2mgl 's help. I can add a branch around the 2nd statement. I actually need this because I want to see the begin label. so you can also do this:

```
/^begin$/,/^end$/{
/begin/{ b skip }
/end/!d
:skip
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you were close to getting it to do what you wanted. When you want to delete the next line after a match you simply need to pull it in with the sed `n` and then hit it with a delete `d`.

It looks like you want to skip the line after the line that starts with `begin` unless it's `end` and print all the other lines.

If so, the following should suffice:

```
/^begin$/,/^end$/{
/begin/{n;/end/!d}
}
```

It works by skipping the next line after begin except if it starts with end (`/end/!`).

Also see: [sed or awk: delete n lines following a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-or-awk-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern)