# bash: delete n lines starting from matching pattern using sed

Tags: bash, sed, solaris, solaris-10

I have a file `aa` containing the following:

```
11
22
33
44
```

If I would like to delete one line matching 22, I use:

```
sed "/22/d" aa
```

And I get 22 removed to show as:

```
11
33
44
```

How to delete n lines starting from a matching pattern? For example, say, I would like to delete 2 lines from matching 22 to get the content as:

```
11
44
```

It's different from [sed or awk: delete n lines following a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-or-awk-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern) , as the solution there does not seem to work on Solaris

Comment: See the comments in the accepted answer on how to make it work on Solaris.

Comment: @fedorqui, bash-3.00$ using sed '/22/,+2d' "aa" yields 
sed: command garbled: /22/,+2d (on solaris). gsed works but not sed that's there on solaris