# How can I delete empty Verilog modules, using sed and xargs?

Tags: sed, xargs

I have empty modules in my Verilog file (written automatically) which I want to remove upon writing the file.
e.g.

```vhdl
module noneed ;  
endmodule
```

My plan is to find these lines and remove them from my file, so I came up with this (non-working) pipeline:

```sh
grep -P -A 1 -n 'module \S+ \;' myfile.v \
  | perl -p -e 's/(\d+).*/$1/' \
  | grep -v '-' \
  | xargs -0 -i sed '{}d' myfile.v
```

My line: find empty modules, take their line numbers (and the line after) and feed it to `sed` for removing.

What have I done wrong here and how can I fix my one-liner to actually remove the lines?

BTW,
`xargs` is cool and everything, but I don't care for a solution not using it.

**Edit**
here's a test text:

```
buf syn_1 ( .a ( clkin ) , .vcc ( vcc ) ,  .vss ( vss ) ) ;  
endmodule  
module some_bu11shit_module_nobody_needs_234 ;  
endmodule  
module a_real_module ( clk , inputs , vcc , vss ) ;  
input  clk ;
```

**EDIT2**
desired output:

```
buf syn_1 ( .a ( clkin ) , .vcc ( vcc ) ,  .vss ( vss ) ) ;  
endmodule  
module a_real_module ( clk , inputs , vcc , vss ) ;  
input  clk ;
```

Comment: It seems you already use Perl. Why not to use [Verilog::Parser](http://p3rl.org/Verilog::Parser)?

Comment: never used it (or heard of it till now). in any case, i'm aiming to a one-liner and i don't know how to use CPANs in oneliners

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed or awk: delete n lines following a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-or-awk-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern

Comment: @Sundeep - thanks for the links, but sed doesn't support PCRE regex syntax, so I really can't give it a pattern that describes things of the sort of `a_one234five_cell_name`

Comment: GNU sed supports `\S` and all POSIX tools support `[^[:space:]]` .. and you can use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` if those are the valid characters allowed

Comment: I'm in a tcsh (should be GNU), in any case, neither `sed -e '/module \S+ \;/,+1d'` or `'/module [^[:space:]] \;/,+1d'` works.
Thanks for your effort, btw...

Comment: Can you show the desired output corresponding to your test input?  That would help clarify the question.  As it is, I don't see why a simple `sed -i -e '/^module noneed/,/endmodule/' *.v` isn't sufficient.

Comment: @Sundeep - getting `sed: invalid option -- 'E'` when using -E  
@TobySpeight - edited the question to have the desired output as well

Comment: got it!
thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of @Sundeep, I came up with this line that does it super quick.

`sed -i -re '/module \S+ ;/,+1d' myfile.v`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e '/\bmodule[^(]*$/,/endmodule/d' myfile.v`

For any line with word boundary + `module` and no open parens, delete until endmodule.

Effectively removes modules with no pins, for typical ways of formatting Verilog.

A robust solution would instead use semicolons as line delimiters.

That said, this is `/START/,/END/{ ... }` syntax we use with sed quite a lot editing netlists:

```
sed \
    -e '/\.SUBCKT DELETEME\b/,/\.ENDS/d' \
    -e '/module DELETETHISTOO\b/,/endmodule/d' \
    input-file > output-file
```

... because even though spice can have line continuations and verilog can have arbitrary line breaks until a semicolon, most netlisting tools can be told to avoid those more difficult cases.

Comment: your answer seems valid, but it doesn't do the trick. 
ls -l myfile.v
... 65363912 ... myfile.v

sed -e '/module[^(]*$/,/endmodule/d' myfile.v

ls -l myfile.v
... 65363912 ... myfile.v

Comment: Was working worse for me with some broadened testcases.  Need either a line start anchor (`^`) or a word boundary (`\b`) before `module` or it matches every endmodule line.  Hopefully works for you now.