# sed delete block of lines after pattern1 to pattern2, but not the line matching pattern1 itself?

Tags: sed, pattern-matching, blank-line

I am struggling to use sed to work through 'testfile.txt' and every time it encounters a line that starts `delete_me: abc` it will then:

1. leave the line `delete_me: abc` intact
2. but delete all the lines that follow until the next blank line is reached in the file.

eg. I want this input:

```
delete_me: abc
sSAsaAaSA
AsaSAsaSAsa
asASAsS

^--- <blank line>
```

...to be changed to just this one line:

```
delete_me: abc
```

I have tried:

```
sed '/delete_me/ {n;d}' jil_testfile.txt
# deletes only the first line after 'delete_me'

sed '/delete_me/,/^$/d' jil_testfile.txt
# nearly works but deletes the 'delete_me' line too which I want to stay preserved.
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Generally, if you need to preserve state over multiple lines, better to use awk or perl, the code is cleaner.

Comment: This question is different since you want to **delete a variable number of lines after pattern1, until you match pattern2 (blank line,in your case)**. The more basic task is [sed or awk: delete n lines following a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-or-awk-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;/delete_me/{p;:b;n;//ba;bb};p' file
```

Print lines as normal until the first occurrence of `delete_me`. Print this line and do not print any further lines unless that line contains `delete_me`.

As the spec has changed since I wrote the first solution, here is new one:

```
sed -n '/delete_me/{p;:a;n;/^$/b;ba};p' file
```