# sed or awk: delete/comment n lines following a pattern before 3 lines

Tags: sed

To delete/comment 3 lines befor a pattern (including the line with the pattern):

how can i achive it through sed command

Ref:
[sed or awk: delete n lines following a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-or-awk-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern)

the above ref blog help to achive the this with after a pattern match but i need to know before match

```
define host{
use                             xxx;
host_name                       pattern;
alias                           yyy;
address                         zzz;
}
```

the below sed command will comment the '#' after the pattern match for example

```
sed -e '/pattern/,+3 s/^/#/' file.cfg

define host{
use                             xxx;
#host_name                       pattern;
#alias                           yyy;
#address                         zzz;
#}
```

like this how can i do this for the before pattern?

can any one help me to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

If tac is allowed :
 `tac|sed -e '/pattern/,+3 s/^/#/'|tac`

If tac isn't allowed :
`sed -e '1!G;h;$!d'|sed -e '/pattern/,+3 s/^/#/'|sed -e '1!G;h;$!d'`
(source : http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the file, comment the 3 lines *after*, then re-reverse the file.

```sh
tac file | sed '/pattern/ {s/^/#/; N; N; s/\n/&#/g;}' | tac
```

```
#define host{
#use                             xxx;
#host_name                       pattern;
alias                           yyy;
address                         zzz;
}
```

Although I think awk is a little easier to read:

```sh
tac file | awk '/pattern/ {c=3} c-- > 0 {$0 = "#" $0} 1' | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/&/3;Ta;/pattern[^\n]*$/s/^/#/mg;P;D' file
```

Gather up 4 lines in the pattern space and if the last line contains `pattern` insert `#` at the beginning of each line in the pattern space.

To delete those 4 lines, use:

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/&/3;Ta;/pattern[^\n]*$/d;P;D' file
```

To delete the 3 lines before `pattern` but not the line containing `pattern` use:

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/&/3;Ta;/pattern[^\n]*$/s/.*\n//;P;D'
```